# How to show every second user different types of banners?

Tags: php, options

I have to create the next feature fore the project:

We have two type of top-bar lines. We need to show every second user(or user session I think it's more easy) different types of banners. Okay I created a really simple code for this propose:
//Create a session
session_start();

```
if(isset( $_SESSION ) ){
    $_SESSION['visitCount']++;

    //Create the option for adding here the session value
    add_option( 'banner_counter', $_SESSION['visitCount'] );
    
    //Get curren value from the option table
    $sessionValue = get_option('banner_counter');

    //Added the value of new current session to the value from the optiontable
    $TotalSession = $sessionValue + 1;

    //Updat the option value for showing it on the admin section
    update_option( 'banner_counter', $TotalSession  );
}else{
    $_SESSION['visitCount']=1;
}
```

For displing different banner I used the next code:

```
 <?php if($_SESSION['visitCount'] % 2): ?>

  <h2>Banner One</h2>

 <?php else: ?>

  <h2>Banner One</h2>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

And it works. But I afraid this is not correct solution used wp_option() for my propose. May be everybody could help me giving advise in this area.

Comment: Wonder if it would be sufficient to just randomly choose the banners from equal weight? Like a coin flip with no memory or stateless. Many ads/banners are displayed that way.

Comment: @birgire No-no it's not an ads banner.  We just want to know which banner will work best, in terms of user experience

Comment: When you say user, are we talking about anonymous users or actual logged in users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the [Options API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/options-api/), you'd be better off using the [Transients API](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/), however in either case you'll be polluting the `*_options` table (even if you use transients with expiration times).

I'd **possibly recommend** using [**wp-session-manager**](https://github.com/ericmann/wp-session-manager) plugin by [EAMann's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/46/eamann) which will allow you to use and store `$_SESSION` data in a dedicated sessions database table that the plugin creates upon activation (or where it does not exist).

Reading:

- https://github.com/ericmann/wp-session-manager
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager (Plugin Repo)
- https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/options-api/

Answer (score 2):

You could set a cookie that identifies a user as belonging to either group, then based on the cookie display different things.

And I think there is no need to save the counter, you can randomly assign a new user to a group.